# Cocos2D: Obtaining the text from a CCMenuItemFont

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I simply can't figure out how to obtain the label of a CCMenuItemFont.

**Background**
I'm building a simple hangman game for the iPad. For entering the next guess, I've added 26 buttons to the UI (one for each letter of the alphabet) and wired them all to the same event handler.

Now, inside the event handler, I'd like to obtain the label of the button to update the current guess, but CCMenuItemFont apparently doesn't respond to `text` or `label`.

**Problem**
So - what method can I use to obtain the label of a CCMenuItem?

**Code**
Code for creating the buttons:

```
-(void)addButtons {
    NSArray* charArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",
      @"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",
      @"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:45];

    NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < [charArray count]; ++i) {
      CCMenuItemLabel* buttonMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont 
        itemWithString:(NSString*)[charArray objectAtIndex:i] 
        target:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
      buttonMenuItem.color = ccBLACK;      
      buttonMenuItem.position = ccp(60 + (i/13)*40, 600 - (i%13)*40);
      [buttonArray addObject:buttonMenuItem];       
    }
    CCMenu *buttonMenu = [CCMenu menuWithArray:buttonArray];
    buttonMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:buttonMenu];
}
```

And the event handler:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    // Get a reference to the button that was tapped
    CCMenuItemFont *button = (CCMenuItemFont *)sender;
    [_guess addObject:[button text]]; // this throws an exception because text is the wrong method
    [self paintCurrentGuess];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding to your menu a `CCMenuItemLabel`, not a `CCMenuItemFont` (which actually extends the first one). In both cases, you need to access to the inner `label` containing the text.-

```
CCMenuItemLabel *button = (CCMenuItemLabel *)sender;
NSString *label = button.label.string;
```

Comment: Doh! I knew it must be something obvious (I was using a CCMenuItemFont because I played around with rotating the label). Thanks a lot. (I'll try it later today and accept the answer afterwards).

Comment: Hope it helps. Actually, it may depend on your version (I'm on 1.x), but I'm pretty sure this haven't changed in 2.x.